# Update and log-in hazzles

Tags: upgrade

I am totally new at Ubuntu and have the 11.4 version on my laptop after getting fed up with windows.  I cant download updates using Update manager - I get the bug #783594) and see the following comment:
   * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via long apt URL (LP: #783594)
     - check URL for length and shorten it for error dialog in
       AptUrl/AptUrl.py, AptUrl/Parser.py, tests/apturlparse.py.
     - Patch thanks to Micheal Vogt
     - CVE number pending

I don't know where to find the URL, how to check it, nor how to shorten
 it to

My second problem is that when I want to install software from the UBUNTU Software centre I either get a message "Install from safe site only" or nothing at all.  Even when after clicking on the install button it says "installing" yet the software is not installed.

Thirdly my Firefox won't log into Face boob.

Can any help a frustrated beginner.

best wishes from south Africa

Uwe

Comment: Welcome aboard - this site encourages a Question and Answer approach - you've got at least two questions there that you can open.  Please type into a terminal the following - copy and paste the output into your question.  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking at a [description of one of the recent updates](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apturl/apturl_0.4.2ubuntu5.1/changelog) to your computer:

[image: screenshot]

You don't have to do anything. These descriptions are displayed in the Update Manager to explain what each software update does.

Try clicking the **Check** button in Update Manager to see if there are still updates that need to be installed. If there are any, just click the **Install Updates** button.

If it looks like there are problems with checking for or installing updates, try running the command-line equivalent of Update Manager in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, edit your original question to include the results for us to read.

---

For the other issues you mentioned, please start new questions so that this site can track the answers to each question separately.